# appropriate message for teleop node to control an quadrotor

Tags: ros, quadcopter, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,guys
i would like to ask, which standard message i can use to control a quadrotor by a joystick/gamepad.
I want the node to publish three angels and thrust.Is there a standard message i can use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27731/appropriate-message-for-teleop-node-to-control-an-quadrotor/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, teleop is done using [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) msgs. This represents desired velocities in x, y, z, and about all three axes of rotation.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-02-17**:
hi Dimitri thanks, i send you an email . you got it?